# Finding all BTC transactions from Dec,2017

Tags: bitcoin-core, raw-data

I am doing a research and for that i need all successful BTC transactions that happened in Dec,2017. Is there a way to download this data ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the services of Blockchair for that, here is all the transaction that happened between the 1 and 31 december 2017 on the bitcoin blockchain:

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions?q=time(2017-12-01..2017-12-31)

For download you can scroll to the date you want here: https://gz.blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions/ and download each day of december